# Changing column names for CSV export in Webform results download page

Tags: 8, webforms

This should be very basic. Unfortunately I couldn't find any page that provides specific instructions on how to do this. If anyone can point me in the right direction, much obliged.

Basically I just need to automatically rearrange and change the names of a few columns when I go to the submissions results download page in Webforms. That way, when I export in CSV, I get the column names I want instead of the ones I created in the actual webform.

I'm aware you can do this via a view, but I would like more specific instructions... Anyone know of any guide that can point me in a right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: Try this answer from the Webform maintainer himself https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54797044/can-i-re-order-columns-in-exporting-csv-on-drupal-8-webform-submissions

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the column title of an exported element, the simplest solution is to specify an 'Admin title' via the element edit form's 'Advanced' tab under the 'Administration' detail widget.